# Unable to fetch request in react(client-side) and express server

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express

Iam trying to fetch request from backend in form of post and it seems like my backend and frontend are not serving together
React SignIn code(Client-side)

```
onSubmitSignIn=()=>{
      fetch('http://localhost:3000/signin',{
        method:"POST",
        headers:{'Content-Type':'application/json'},
        body: JSON.stringify({
          email:this.state.signInEmail,
          password:this.state.signInPassword
        })
      })
      .then(response=>response.json())
      .then(data=>{
        if(data==='success'){
        this.props.OnRouteChange('home');
        }
      })
      
  }
```

Server side

```
const express = require('express');
const bodyparser= require('body-parser');
const cors = require('cors');

const app=express();
app.use(bodyparser.json());
app.use(cors());

app.post('/signin', (req,res)=>{
    if(req.body.email===database.users[0].email && req.body.password===database.users[0].password){
        res.json('success');
    }
    else{
        res.status(400).json("error");
    }
})
```

PS:Reactapp is running on port 3001 and server on port 3000.
also when i try signing in the request is in form of get method although i am using post method

[image: netwok panel image]

Comment: If the react and express app will run on the same domain it will be better to [set a proxy](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/proxying-api-requests-in-development/) you can then do `fetch('/signin',{` Your fetch is correct and I don't see a reason why it would not perform a POST.

Comment: What's happening? Do you get any errors messages?

Comment: First of all: you don't catch error in react code. That's why you don't know whether you have error or not. Second: `success` string is not valid json response. It should be at least `{result: "success"}`

Comment: @KenBekov  it shows the following error in the console ...........................          TypeError: NetworkError when attempting to fetch resource

Comment: @KenBekov i tried the  {result: "success"}  but no effect.

Comment: @hmr I posted the ss of network panel

Comment: @Saumyamishra you can copy the fetch from your question and paste it in the console, when you run it there I'm sure it doesn't make a GET request.